# css tables: fixed column with alternate row colors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

I'm trying to create a table with a fixed first column and colouring alternate rows.  I've got the first column fixed, and alternate rows coloured using nth-child.  The problem is that the alternate row colours is not applied to the fixed column.  See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericdsouza/j9bv5aon/).  This is my first attempt at css so I'm sure I'm missing something fairly obvious.

html

```
<div class="wb-standings-table"><table class="standings">
  <tr>
    <td class="wb-standings-col1"><b>Player</b></td>
    <th>PTS↑</th>
    <th>PPR</th>
    <th>TPP</th>
    <th>SPC</th>
    <th>TUG</th>
    <th>LOG</th>
    <th>CRK</th>
    <th>EUC</th>
    <th>PKR↓</th>
    <th>DRT</th>
    <th>PNG</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wb-standings-col1">Chuck</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">9</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">15</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">24</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">-</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">2</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">-</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">3</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">3</td>
    <td class="wb-green">0</td>
    <td class="wb-green">1</td>
    <td class="wb-green">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wb-standings-col1">Rico</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">4</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">10</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">14</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">-</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">0</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">3</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">-</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">0</td>
    <td class="wb-green">0</td>
    <td class="wb-green">1</td>
    <td class="wb-gray">0</td>
  </tr>
```

css

```
.wb-standings-container {
    width:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.wb-standings-header {
    font-size:1.5em;
    margin:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.wb-standings-footer {
    font-size:.8em;
    margin:8px;
}
.wb-standings-table {
    overflow-x:auto;  
    margin-left:100px; 
    overflow-y:visible;
}
table.standings {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table.standings th {
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:#808080;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
table.standings td {
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    min-width: 50px;
}
table.standings tr:nth-child(even) {background: #f2f2f2}
table.standings tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
table.standings td:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
table.standings td:nth-child(4) {border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;}
table.standings tr:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

table.standings .wb-standings-col1 {
    position:absolute; 
    width:90px; 
    left:8px;
    top:auto;
    text-align:left;
    color:#057aff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a special case to the col1 class like so:

```
table.standings tr:nth-child(even),
table.standings tr:nth-child(even) .wb-standings-col1 {
  background: #f2f2f2
} 
table.standings tr:nth-child(odd),
table.standings tr:nth-child(odd) .wb-standings-col1 {
  background: #FFF
}
```

You can add another selector to the same CSS definition by using a comma to separate. That way you can still control both definitions by modifying a single CSS spec.

As to why this is happening.... I'm not really sure. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the `.wb-standings-col1` class is positioned absolutely and that messes with the rendering of the table underneath. I've noticed in Chrome's dev tools that that particular cell is set to `display: block` but the rest of the cells are set to `display: table-cell`. That may be another reason for it. Someone else will have to give you that answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You made the background color on "tr" tag, but your first "td" stays outside of the "tr". To fix this you should use background on the "td" instead of "tr":

```
table.standings tr:nth-child(even) td {background: #f2f2f2}
table.standings tr:nth-child(odd) td {background: #FFF}
```

and change its width to 100px:

```
table.standings .wb-standings-col1 {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100px; 
    left:8px;
    top:auto;
    text-align:left;
    color:#057aff;
}
```

Also I think you should remove the box-shadow of this:

```
table.standings td:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    /*box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
}
```

Comment: thanks -- this also worked, but i had already accepted the first answer.  I'm not sure i understand why the first "td" stays outside of the "tr" - can you explain a bit more?   (the box-shadow is incomplete, i started working on it while i was trying to figure out the problem above.  eventually it's supposed to provide a shadow for the fixed column so the scrolling columns look like they scroll under the fixed column, like on the ESPN scoreboard)

Comment: Your table is far 100px from left because it is inside the div .wb-standings-table which is margin-left 100px. So your "tr"s are also 100px from left. But the first "td"s have style "position: absolute" and "left: 8px" that means they are far 8px from left.